# Zend Framework 1 and 2: Get individual headMeta() values

Tags: zend-framework, seo, zend-framework2

I'm working on 2 sites, one of which is Zend Framework 1 and the other Zend Framework 2. I'm already on the SEO part and I need to use the values of each of the meta elements.

I've already made a workaround to get the title by doing this:

```
print strip_tags($this->headTitle())
```

But for the meta tags, I'm still figuring it out.

Question: Is there a way to do this from view?:

```
print $this->headMeta('keywords')
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: So which is it ZF1 or ZF2?

Comment: this is zf2 framework

Comment: I would appreciate it if both.

Answer (score -1):

just call the `getValue` method of the viewhelper

```
    $this->headMeta()->setName('keywords', 'foo bar', array('lang' => 'us_en', 'scheme' => 'foo', 'bogus' => 'unused'));
```

brings you

```
    stdClass Object
    (
        [type] => name
        [name] => keywords
        [content] => foo bar
        [modifiers] => Array
        (
            [lang] => us_en
            [scheme] => foo
            [bogus] => unused
        )
    )
```

otherwise call the `getContainer` method to receive the complete storage container (with all values) from the headMeta Helper

Comment: You mean like this: $this->headMeta()->getValue('keywords')